# INSERT statement does not work from PHP Code, but works in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm having a problem with an SQL Query from php

The Query is

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pwn_users` (`name`,`email`,`password`) values ('$chosen_name','$chosen_mail','$chosen_pw')"))
```

When I print the Query text like this:

```
    print "INSERT INTO `pwn_users` (`name`,`email`,`password`) values ('$chosen_name','$chosen_mail','$chosen_pw')";
```

it will return my inputs like this:

```
INSERT INTO `pwn_users` (`name`,`email`,`password`) values ('Testuser','testmail@test.us','testpass')
```

The data though is not inserted into the table. But when I copy that last statement directly into phpmyAdmin's SQL Querybox it will insert correctly.

Comment: Do you have an open connection?

Comment: beside that you probably want to use prepared statements, do you connect with the correct user? Test if select is working, maybe you have some connection problems. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: If you can, try using PHP's `mysqli` library instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Or even better use PDO (this is not an answer though).

Comment: +1 @PeeHaa's comment, to expand: You must have called `mysql_connect()` before you call `mysql_query()`, you must have used a user account that has permission to modify the target database/table to connect, and you must either specify the database name in the query or call `mysql_select_db()` before the query. For debugging purposes, you can find out why the query failed by doing `mysql_query($queryStr) or die(mysql_error());` - but **never** show the output of `mysql_error()` in a production environment.

Comment: the last ) in the first code block is a typo. i'm calling other mysql_queries before that and those do work. im connected to the databse

Comment: Ok so mysql_error gave me an error that one field i dont declare in the query doesn't have a default value. going to fix that in the table directly. thanks

Comment: If that is the case you didn't ran the exact same query in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @user1211030 You set a default value in the database itself - you can use PHPMyAdmin to do it. If you go to the table and click the `Structure` tab at the top, then click the `Edit` link (little pen) for the field in question, you have an option called `Default` - set the drop-box to 'as defined' then enter a default value in the text field below. This is not likely to be a "fatal" error though - the row would likely still be inserted (depending on the data type of the missing column). Although as @PeeHaa says, it sounds like you didn't run the same query in PMA - please post the exact error.

Comment: I gave every field i dont set in the query a default value and it does work now. Thanks everyone

Comment: Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo or not, but your first line of code has one abundant `)` at the end and it's missing a semi-colon.

If you use `mysql_query()` with only one parameter it uses ["the last link opened by mysql_connect()"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Are you sure you have an open connection?

If you are sure you have an open connection you can always try calling `mysql_error()` after calling `mysql_query()` to get more information about possible errors.

EDIT; in response to the other answers; there is nothing wrong with your quotes, apostrophes or reversed apostrophes.

Comment: mysql_query($queryStr) or die(mysql_error());mysql_error gave me an error that one field i dont declare in the query doesn't have a default value. going to fix that in the table directly. insert works after every field i dont call in the query has a default value. ou set a default value in the database itself - you can use PHPMyAdmin to do it. If you go to the table and click the Structure tab at the top, then click the Edit link (little pen) for the field in question, you have an option called Default - set the drop-box to 'as defined' then enter a default value in the text field below.